# Error during tentative install/try many Ubuntu distros on Samsung Smart Ativ 500t

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, 32-bit

After following many other answers from similar situation I finally was able to boot USB live distros in my Samsung Ativ 500t, a pretty old PC with horrible hardware Intel Atom Cherry Z3760 with PowePC GPU.

After many efforts when I select in Grub Try or Install Ubuntu/Mate/Lubuntu and others, it seems to start, gives some errors of GPIO not being able to be address in IrQ and some logo of start shows up to finally say that the media of installation cannot be found.

I understand this particular hardware is not so easy to handle (32 bits for processor and EFI), but it seems I’m close to getting it to work, it seems that for some reason after getting into GRUB the partitions just get lost.

What can I do to solve the error:

```
(initramfs) unable to find a live medium containing a live file system
```

when trying to *install* or *try* any Ubuntu and derivatives in my Atom Z3760?

I have already tried different pendrives, and I have already tried removing and plugging it back in.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: @David, just edit to show more clear my question